# Railroad diagrams with D3.js

Tags: d3.js

I am looking for an example of railroad diagrams in D3.js. The type of diagram I would like to create is shown in the screenshot. So far I have not found any implementations in D3.js.

[image: railroad diagram]

I have been searching flow charts and trees in the D3.js example repositories.

Comment: Try googling "D3 js decision tree", should give you a couple of sample codepen codes to work with. Good luck!